# Inconsistency in suggested edit count

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

I think I found a bug on Stack Overflow, would like to have feedback if it is, so you can eventually fix it!

If I go on my personal profile in SO on the activity tab and select the suggestion button (in order to see all edits I have suggested) I see 19 entries:

[image]

However, if I select one of the suggested edits and follow the link I see in my Editor Stats that I actually have 20 edit suggestions, and so it looks as if one went lost.

[image]

What's going on?

Which stat is correct? (Don't know if it's of any use but I remember doing 20...)

EDIT:

new proof of bug added, if I go on my review section in the lateral tab I'll see this recapitulation, which goes against editor stats

[image]

Comment: Maybe you edited a question or answer that has since been deleted?

Comment: @Mat Shouldn't it remain saved?I noticed that there are 2 questions with same title though...could it be that?

Comment: One of those is an edit on the question, the other is an edit to one of the answers to that question. No problem there. I'm guessing suggested edits on deleted posts stay accounted for, but you can't find them in the edit history since the post "has gone". I don't know if that is indeed the case, but I suspect that might be the case.

Comment: @Mat don't know...look what I found in my review progress tab. It goes againts editor stats. This seems to disprove your suggestion..new ideas? ;D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an approved edit (approved Dec 27 at 20:39) on a question titled:

> Dont understand this Logcat on a INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

(You can see it by going at the bottom of [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/170152) for instance.)

The suggested edit [link](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/167842) is dead right now, which I believe means the question was deleted (I can't find that post). All your other suggested edits seem live.

So what seems to be happening is:

1. the "Editor Stats" count all edits, live or not
2. the "Suggestions" page lists only live edits
3. the reviewer badges only take live (and approved obviously) edits into account

I believe 3. is not really controversial.
Item 2 is consistent with the rest of the information in there (questions, answers, comments disappear when the associated post is deleted).
Item 1 is "the problem". On the one hand, you *did* make that edit, so the stat makes sense. On the other, that edit doesn't really exist anymore (neither does its associated rep), so it doesn't really "count".

I'm not sure if item 1 is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), or an oversight (or due to caching), but if it's a bug, I'd squarely classify it in the really minor buglet department.

Comment: your answer seems to have cleared the problem, still I have a last question: shouldn't point 3 be consistent with point 1? If an edit is conuted when it's made (not regarding live post or not) then also badge assigning should take account of it. Or in the other way neither edit stats should count it.

Comment: I don't think so. Reputation gains (and thus privileges) are lost on posts that get deleted (badges aren't removed, but, for stackable badges, post deletion does have an effect). Counting deleted suggested edits would be inconsistent with the rest of the system IMO.