# Which of these suggested edits count is correct?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, badge-progress

I have got three different suggested edit counts on my [SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1184435/devraj-gadhavi). I am wondering which one is correct.

First, one is my [activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1184435/devraj-gadhavi?tab=activity), it shows the suggested edit count as *67*.

[image: Activity Tab]

Second, when I look at the detail of any suggestion, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3820138) one and click on More, I get *Editor Stats*, which says “Devraj Gadhavi had *69* edit suggestions approved, and *5* edit suggestions rejected”.

[image: Editor Status]

Third, when I look at the review queue for [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) or [Late Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers) and hover my mouse over the badge progress bar it shows *45* against [Copy Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/223/copy-editor).

[image: Badge Progress Bar]

By searching the [meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), I have come to conclusion that the 2nd one could be due to some posts being deleted, after my suggested edit was approved.
But what about the 3rd one? Which is correct? 1st or 3rd?

---

**EDIT**

This is not answered by [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117585/217907) similar question.

As, according to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117585/217907) answer

> So what seems to be happening is:
>
> 1. the "Editor Stats" count all edits, live or not
> 2. the "Suggestions" page lists only live edits
> 3. the reviewer badges only take live (and approved obviously) edits into account

If `2` and `3` both show only live edits, then they should be equal. But they are not.

My suggested edits are

1. 69 + 5 in *editor stats*.
2. 67 in *suggestions* page
3. 45 in the *badge progress*

Comment: @Duncan I had checked this question before posting. But I don't get my answer from *3 possible things happening* in the [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117585/217907).

Comment: Does there need to be a correct value? The answer in the duplicate seems to explain how all the numbers are reached.

Comment: @Duncan I have edited the question to reflect the difference.

Comment: badge progress doesn't consider some suggested edits, specifically retag only edits.  There is a duplicate to that somewhere.

Comment: I suppose one option here is to continue to close this question, but improve the other answer with the facts @psubsee2003 has highlighted.

Comment: I don't mind this question being closed. But how would I get the link to the other improved answer?

Comment: @Duncan yeah, that seems ideal since the original answer is lacking on details,

Comment: @psubsee2003 Are you confident enough of the facts to make that edit?

Comment: @Duncan Yes I am, but I'd say amimuson took care of it.

Comment: @psubsee2003 F5 is my friend apparently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. **69 + 5 in editor stats**

   This value is correct. These numbers represent the *total* number of approved and rejected (respectively) suggested edits you've ever had on your account.
2. **67 in suggestions page**

   This value is correct. This number represents the total number of suggestions (whether approved or rejected) on posts that *haven't since been deleted*. Activity on deleted posts does not show up in your activity history (except when still cached), so those suggested edits won't show up there and don't reflect in the count.
3. **45 in the badge progress**

   This value is correct. This number represents the total number of edits that you've had approved and *also count towards the editing badges*. Not all edits count towards the badges, as explained in the [list of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732):

   > - Edits on deleted posts do not count
   > - Edits to your own posts do not count
   > - Edits to community wiki posts do count
   > - Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count
   > - Tag wiki edits do count
   > - Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges do count, once approved
   > - Each edited post counts only once, regardless of how many additional edits you may submit